# Separating lines of a huge file into two files depending on the date

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm gathering tones of data in a stream on an Ubuntu machine, the data is stored in days packages (where each day_file contains somewhere between 1 and 5 gb). I'm not an experienced linux/bash/awk user, but the data looks something like this (all lines start with a date):

```
2020-08-31T23:59:59Z !RANDOM numbers and letters
2020-08-31T23:59:59Z $Enconding the data
2020-09-01T00:00:00Z !In a unreadable way
```

Now to the problem, the stream is cut around midnight local time (for a few reasons it can't be cut at exact 00.00.00 gtm time). This means that rows from two dates are stored in the same file and I want to separate them into the correct date files. I wrote the following script trying to separate the rows, it works but it takes several hours to run and I think that there must be a faster way of doing this operation?

```
#!/bin/bash

dateDiff (){
    line_str="$1"
    dte1="2020-09-01"
    dte2=${line_str:0:10}
    if [[ "$dte1" == "$dte2" ]]; then 
        echo $line_str >> correct_date.txt; 
    else 
        echo $line_str >> wrong_date.txt; 
    fi
}

IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(cat massive_file.txt)
do
    dateDiff "$line"
done
unset IFS
```

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in form of code, could you please post sample of expected output in your question and let us know then for better understanding of question.

Answer (score 3):

Using this awk script I'm able to process 10GB file in approx 1 minute on my machine.

```sh
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /^2020-08-31/) { print $0 > "correct.txt" } else { print $0 > "wrong.txt" }  }' input_file_name.txt
```

Line is checked against regular expression containing your date, then whole line is printed to file based on regexp match.

Comment: Checking for `$0 ~ /^date/` will be faster than `$1`, because for each line `awk` will do this without splitting to fields, for a large input, you can see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk with `T` as your field separator, the first field, `$1`, will be the date. Then you can output each record to a file named for the date.

```
$ cat file
2020-08-31T23:59:59Z !RANDOM numbers and letters
2020-08-31T23:59:59Z $Enconding the data
2020-09-01T00:00:00Z !In a unreadable way

$ awk -FT '{ print > ($1 ".txt") }' file

$ ls 20*.txt
2020-08-31.txt  2020-09-01.txt

$ cat 2020-09-01.txt 
2020-09-01T00:00:00Z !In a unreadable way

$ cat 2020-08-31.txt 
2020-08-31T23:59:59Z !RANDOM numbers and letters
2020-08-31T23:59:59Z $Enconding the data
```

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- Using a bash loop to read logs would be very slow.
- Using `awk`, `sed`, `grep` or similar is very good, but still you will have to read and write whole files line by line, and this has a perfomance ceiling.
- For your specific case, you could only identify the split points, which can be 3, not only 2, (previous, current and next day logs can co-exist in a file) with something like `grep -nm1 "^$day"` and then split the log file with a combination of `head` and `tail`, like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163399/split-a-file-into-two). Then append or prepend them to the existing ones. This would be a very fast solution because you would write the files massively, not line by line.

---

Here is a simple solution with `grep`, as you need to test only the 10 first characters of the log lines, and for this job `grep` is faster than `awk`.

Assuming that you store logs in a destination directory, every incoming file should pass from something like this script. Order of processing is important, you have to follow date order of the files, e.g. you see that I append to an existing file. This is just a demo solution for guidance.

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -f "$1" ]] && f="$1" || { echo "Nothing to do"; exit 1; }

dest_dir=archive/
suffix="_file.log"

curr=${f:0:10}
prev=$( date -d "$curr -1 day" "+%Y-%m-%d" )
next=$( date -d "$curr +1 day" "+%Y-%m-%d" )

for d in $prev $curr $next; do
    grep "^$d" "$f" >> "${dest_dir}${d}${suffix}"
done
```